# Why does faithful module induce injection between Hom?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, injective-module

This is from a [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aspm/1527702068) of Matsumura:

[image]

The line that I don't understand is the faithfulness of $E$ implies injection $\text{Hom}(D,D) \rightarrow \text{Hom}(E,D)$. Why is this true?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, $\operatorname{Hom}_A(D,D)=A$ means that the obvious map $A\to \operatorname{Hom}_A(D,D)$ is an isomorphism, so that every homomorphism $D\to D$ is given by multiplication by some element of $A$.  Since the restriction map $\operatorname{Hom}_A(D,D)\to\operatorname{Hom}_A(E,D)$ is surjective, this means the same is true for homomorphisms $E\to D$: all of them are given by multiplication by some element of $A$.  Since $E$ is faithful, multiplication by any nonzero element of $A$ is nonzero on $E$, and so the map $\operatorname{Hom}_A(D,D)\to\operatorname{Hom}_A(E,D)$ is injective (since all that map does is take multiplication by an element $a\in A$ on $D$ and restrict it to $E$).

Comment: So basically, if I have a ring $A$, and if I have a homomorphism $A \rightarrow \text{Hom}(B,C)$, then I can view this as inducing a map $\phi_a(b) = a\cdot b \in C$, right?

Comment: Sure.  But in this case that's kind of backwards: $D$ and $E$ are $A$-modules, so we already know how to multiply their elements by elements of $A$.